# Asterisk Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am trying to read through the Cech Cohomology section in these [notes](http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eedixhovensj/teaching/2011-2012/AAG/lecture_14.pdf)

I would be really grateful if someone could explain to me what $f_*$ means. Sorry in advance if this is just something standard.

Extract:

> Proposition 2. $\mathrm{H}^{0}(\check{\mathrm{c}}(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{F}))=\mathcal{F}(X)$
>
> Proof. Exercise: this is just a reformulation of the sheaf property.
> There is a sheaf-theoretic version of the Cech complex. For any open $V \subset X$ denote by $f: V \rightarrow X$ the inclusion. Then define
> $$
> \mathcal{C}^{p}(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{F})=\prod_{v \in I^{p+1}} f_{*} \mathcal{F}_{\mid U_{v}}
> $$
> These form a complex $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{F})$ of sheaves on $X$ with the property that $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{C})=\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$. Note that there is a natural map $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{0}(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{F})$ given by sending a section $s$ to its restrictions on all the components.

Comment: It is the direct image functor.

Comment: thanks! very quick response :)

Comment: In fact, and answers don't belong to the comment boxes ...

Comment: To be honest, I was half-expecting a follow-up question of, "what is the direct image functor?"

Comment: was reading online to find that out but if you have time to explain it to me then by all means, it would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map and $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf on $X$, then $f_* \mathscr{F}$ is the sheaf on $Y$ defined by the following formula:
$$f_* \mathscr{F} (V) = \mathscr{F} (f^{-1} V)$$
This is called the **direct image sheaf**. You should verify that the formula indeed defines a sheaf.